# ASP.NET WebForms vs MVC [after VS2010/.NET 4.0 announcement]

Tags: model-view-controller, webforms, .net-4.0, asp.net-4.0

Two of the biggest advantages of MVC over webforms were non-existent viewstate and URL routing. VS2010 and .NET 4.0 incorporates built-in URL routing for Webforms as well as better control for viewstate.

I advocate use of MVC for extranet sites due to the MVC design pattern and its general lightweight nature but in light of this new announcement has Webforms closed the gap? Why would you still pick MVC over Webforms?

Thanks

Comment: I believe your fate will be similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662540/any-one-like-me-who-still-believes-in-aspnet-web-forms-or-has-evryone-switched-t

Comment: Why? I am looking for comments from practitioners on why and where they use MVC/Webforms given the new enhancements and not just because one prefers a certain style over the other. Some case studies or success stories where choosing one over the other would be helpful as well.

Comment: MVC all the way. Webforms can die. Religious war, though. If u don't understand the reasons for MVC vs WebForms (there's millions of posts on this) .. even after 4.0 released, then keep reading. MVC == full control + Testing. WebForms = Rapid App Dev at the cost of control + testing.

Comment: Web Forms is the new VB6.  There will be another decade's worth of jobs maintaining those apps before they're eventually ported to MVC.

Comment: The tone of the question seemed argumentative and I don't think there's one "right" answer to this question.  It may generate an interesting discussion though (may be worth making it a community wiki).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're forgetting about 2 main advantages of MVC: better control over generated HTML and better support for test-driven development.

I'd say that normally implementing a site using ASP.NET WebForms would require less effort that implementing exactly the same with MVC.

MVC gives you more control, but it also requires more expertise and effort.